# Why is text overlapping in aged-away post flags?

Tags: bug, flag-history

Recently when I visited my flag history page, I noticed that one of the flagged question titles were overlapping in my flagging history.

**NOTE:**

I'm using the Firefox browser.

Please see below screenshot for the same in Firefox browser:

[image]

The same problem is reproducible in the Google Chrome browser. Check the below screenshot:

[image]

Is this a bug?

Comment: you should probably add which browser you are seeing this

Comment: @SurajRao please check updated question

Comment: well I am having a hard time finding a flag with such a big word in the title in my flagging history. So cant really confirm it

Comment: @SurajRao agree with u but the same thing happen in both `Firefox` and `Chrome`

Comment: I can reproduce looking at your aged away flags on Chrome 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit) for Linux... I have a strange feeling something like this has come up before...

Comment: @JonClements is that a bug?

Comment: I don't know - I'm not a dev... one could argue it's probably by-design and that it's just an insane corner case that's not worth "fixing".

Comment: If this is a bug, it would be good to add what the expected outcome is, in addition to the actual outcome. Would it not also be a bug if they split a word in half, just so it wrapped correctly?

Comment: It borks [the actual question page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45277654), too, at least [on Android Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSf2o.png). I'm pretty sure that's come up before.

Comment: It also breaks the question page on Chrome for Windows

Comment: @MikeM. and Camilo Terevinto  The same problem is reproducible in firefox also