# Still text is overlapping in flag history

Tags: discussion, bug, design, flag-history

Previously I have reported a bug about text overlapping in flag history -
*[Why is text overlapping in aged-away post flags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368363/why-is-text-overlapping-in-aged-away-post-flags)*.

But when I recently checked my flag history I noticed the design of flagging history is changed, but still the same issue exists of text overlapping in the flag history.

Please check the below screenshot for the same:

[image]

The above problem produced in Firefox 61.0.1 (64-bit) and Google Chrome
version 64.0.3282.119.

**UPDATE**

The same problem was *reproduced* in Firefox 63.0.3 (64-bit) and Google Chrome version 64.0.3282.119 (official build) (64-bit).

Comment: Can you repro this on the current versions of those browsers?

Comment: @jhpratt sure please check updated question

Comment: Chrome stable is version 71 currently...

Comment: looks similar as this MSE report: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319779/flag-summary-page-is-mostly-responsive-but-post-titles-overflow-into-the-stat

Comment: There's no reason to repost this. Literally only the sidebar was changed there, nothing else.

Comment: @animuson thanks for info should i delete this question?